# Is UNION ALL resulting in slow PostgresSQL query runtime?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-rds

I have a Postgres query that uses UNION ALL to select the same columns from ~17 different tables. Runtime is very slow and needs to be improved. What is the main determinant in this query's high execution time? Is it the number of SELECTs I have in the query, the number of columns I'm selecting (over 100), or something else?

Tried limiting the number of columns selected and didn't notice an increase in performance. For further context, I have the Postgres query running as an AWS Lambda function triggered by an API Gateway request. New to this so I don't know if the AWS architecture is part of the problem. Would really appreciate any help!

Comment: Capture the query, then put `EXPLAIN` at the start and run it against the database. It will return an **explain plan** that provides performance information. You can then add those details to your Question.

Comment: What you *really* need is `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)`.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the full query and the [execution plan](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/using-explain.html) generated using **`explain (analyze, buffers, format text)`** (_not_ just a "simple" explain) as  [formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) and make sure you preserve the indention of the plan. Paste the text, then put `\`\`\`` on the line before the plan and on a line after the plan.